# Spark Gap for a Tesla Coil with 9-18v battery

Tags: batteries, dc, tesla-coil

I’m working on a university project where I’m building a modest tesla coil formed by a 20cm length secondary and a primary of five loops around the secondary.
I need to make a spark gap in my circuit but without having to buy a transformer, I’ve been searching on the web for a solution and it seems some people managed to make a spark gap using 9v batteries, but never showed the way to do that.
So what’s the best way to make a SG in my circuit?
Ask me if I missed some relevant information about my settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need high voltage in order for a spark gap to operate. Generally speaking you need 1kV in order to jump a 1mm gap (this depends on humidity, altitude, etc but this is the general figure). What they probably did was build a high voltage generator that runs off of 9V batteries (such as a 555 timer based transformer driver).

In your case you'd probably be better off just building a Slayer Exciter circuit (google it for details). It does not require a high voltage to run but still produces small sparks, but is great for demonstrating wireless power transfer (to a fluorescent bulb, for example).

You will not be able to build a SGTC using only low voltage batteries and no high voltage source.

Comment: What doea it take to make a transformer like the one you mentioned?

Comment: Generally you wouldn't want to make the transformer, you would use one that is already made. You would only build the driver. The transformer could be an automotive ignition transformer, a TV line output transformer, an oil burner ignition transformer, or a neon sign transformer (google these for more information). If you use an OBIT or a NST you will not need to build a driver - they run off mains.